# How to save byte[] as wav file in silverlight application?

Tags: c#, file, silverlight, audio, save

In my MVC Application I added a Silverlight Audio Recorder. This recorder record audio `using System.Windows.Media;` namespace as `byte[]` that represents an wav file.

Now I need to save this `byte[]` as `.wav` file on local disk (server).

So far I've tried the following:

```
byte[] audioData; // Here I contain my data     

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Temp\yourfile.wav", this.audioData); // Doesn't work

BinaryWriter Writer = null;
string name = @"C:\Temp\yourfile.wav";

try
{
      Writer = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(name));

      Writer.Write(this.audioData);
      Writer.Flush();
      Writer.Close();
 }
 catch
 {
      ...
 }
```

But nothing work for me... What I did wrong?

Ok. Let's say I can send my data as json string to the controller:

```
WebClient net = new WebClient();
string data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(this.audioData, 0, this.audioData.Length);

net.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("/Home/SaveFile", UriKind.Relative), data);
```

How would I get this data in MVC Action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight is running client side, your MVC code is server-side, so this won't work in it's current guise.

I'd recommend using a web service to send the data back to your server to save it.

Take a look at using [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or maybe [WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api) to get up and running with it.

If you really wanted to do get intricate, you could also use something like [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) to have the client / server (which is essentially what this set up is) send communicate with each other and send the data back through that. Though it seems a *little* overkill for this.